# Python syntax for raising and catching exception, also which exception type to raise

Tags: python, exception, raise

I'm trying to learn how to work with exceptions in Python.
I'm clearly misunderstanding something. It feels like there is a small thing I'm not seeing, so I feel a bit silly ;)
I've looked at many threads and tutorials on this. I'm certain I'm close to doing it right, but a little wrong has pretty much the same effect as completely wrong. ;)

Here's a minimum example:

```
def MyFun():
    print("start MyFun")
    if True:   
        raise Exception("MyFun FAIL")
    print("not here in MyFun")
    return

try:
    MyFun()
except Exception("MyFun FAIL") as e:
    print("some message")
```

MyFun() always raises an exception, and I want to catch it.
When I run this in my interpreter, I get "TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed".

I've changed Exception("MyFun FAIL") to ValueError("MyFun FAIL") just for trying stuff, but get the same message. I don't understand what I'm supposed to do.

In addition, I fail to understand what Exception type I'm supposed to raise. I found [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) but it doesn't do a very good job explaining what I should pick when.
A general description could be helpful for the future. Short term: In my actual case, I intend to read a particular file, and if a certain text string isn't found in it, I know it's not the expected file or it's corrupted, so I want to raise an exception that I can catch and handle in the rest of my code.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: all right, I see the comment, it doesn't crash if I do:

```
def MyFun():
    print("start MyFun")
    if True:   
        raise Exception("MyFun FAIL")
    print("not here in MyFun")
    return

try:
    MyFun()
except Exception as e:
    print("some message")
```

Yet, this doesn't answer my whole question. I know it is not explicit in the original wording, but I didn't want to catch general Exception. I want to adhere to good coding practice not to hide bugs, so I want to raise and catch specific things, and make my code respond in specific ways to these specific things.

Things not answered yet:

1. How do I specifically do something specifically for error "MyFun FAIL" and let the program crash if I get error "whatever else caused by something else"?
2. Which more specific exception type am I supposed to raise when the file does not have the expected contents?

Comment: You meant to write: `except Exception as e:`

Comment: Voting to reopen. With the new `match` statement, it's not entirely unreasonable to think that you could pattern-match on exceptions, with the shown code only catching exceptions with that particular message. (You *can't*, but explaining that is, I think, worth an answer.)

Comment: Which type you choose depends on the semantics you want to convey. Sometimes, it's not obvious. `RuntimeError` is a sort of catch-all, none-of-the-other-types-seems-quite-right exception to raise, though you typically want to define your own custom subtype to raise instead of `RuntimeError` itself.

Comment: You can raise any one of the [builtin exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), and define your own specific classes if that's not granular or descriptive enough.

Comment: @chepner, thanks, apparently I'm trying to do something that's impossible. That explains why it was so hard to find how to do it ;) Now, given my intent to properly handle a specific thing that can go wrong combined with my intent not to cause headaches later on: would the custom subtype of RuntimeError be the preferred way to do this? Or is there a smarter (more robust) way?

Comment: I do like custom subtypes. They can make the actual string a moot point. For example, the type alone of `class MyFunFailed(RuntimeException): pass` carries just as much information as `Exception("MyFun FAIL")`: compare `isinstance(e, MyFunFailed)` with something like `str(e) == "MyFun FAIL"`.